# Can you help me solve this space optimization problem?

Tags: geometry, optimization, packing-problem

I am a high school student doing a mathematics research project and I am in dire need of help! My math project is "determining the crystals needed to bedazzle a top" and the topic might seem extremely silly to most, but when choosing what to write about, I simply could not think of anything else.

So far, I have calculated the total area of the pattern piece, which is about 1144,758 cm^2 and I divided this result by the area of a single crystal with a diameter of 8.4 mm, which gave me the absolute maximum amount of the crystals needed, which is about 2067 pieces.
Afterwards, I divided the total area of the pattern piece by the square in which the crystal fits, which is 0.7056 cm^2, which gave me 1623 pieces which is the minimal amount of the crystals needed. This all due to the fact that I will be placing the crystals in the way that minimizes the space unused as seen in the second picture that I attached.

As you can see, the produced interval is quite huge and I would like to make it more precise. I have been trying to read many articles and solutions to problems like these and I know that @RobPratt specializes in space optimization, however, I am a high school student and these scientific papers are quite...well...scientific..., which I find a bit confusing.

I attached the photo of the pattern pieces and its measurements are 43.2 X 42.0 cm. I will be extremely helpful for any help:)
[pattern piece](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFSsR.jpg)

[the placement of the crystals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECaBE.png)

Comment: @JeanMarie Search Google for 'bedazzled top' images.

Comment: @Daniel Mathias Thanks ! I wasn't one the right track at all !

Answer (score 0):

You must find an appropriate *polygon* for the circle and (perhaps) the container. True, "circles" (for simplicty) *behave* like a *squares* but a *hexagon* is a better *approximation* for a circle than a square and I can see one in the center of your diagram. It's very much like how Archimedes caclulate $\pi$ using polygons. Better your approximation, the more efficient the utilization of space. It's also a *tiling problem* from the looks of it.

Both *size* and *shape* matter as far as I can tell.

Comment: *packing problem* may be more accurate.

Comment: Précisément! On target! 